# No "flash zip from SD card" option on ClockworkMod Recovery

Tags: rooting, nexus-4, clockworkmod-recovery, 5.1-lollipop

I am trying to follow the steps outlined in the following article in order to root my Nexus 4 running Android 5.1:

http://www.teamandroid.com/2015/04/16/root-nexus-4-android-51-lmy47o-lollipop-cwm-supersu/2/

Step 13 instructs that I apply SuperSU with a "flash zip from SD card" command; however, no such command is appearing on my ClockworkMod menu. I have an "Install ZIP" option, but I am not sure whether or not this should accomplish the same function.

I am running ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.7 (Touch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Install Zip** → select the zip file you downloaded (possibly [this](https://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/)) → choose **Yes** if asked, and the recovery should flash this zip into your system.

*Flash zip from SD card* or *Install zip* are basically the same thing.

Comment: To OP: The guide that you linked in the question doesn't mention to update the SuperSu app from Play Store. AFAIK, you'll have to download the app from Play Store after flashing the zip file. Anyhow, follow the guide if it has been proved well for other users.

Comment: I actually already had the SuperSU app installed from my previously rooted 4.2 installation. Thanks for the clarification, though -- and thanks very much for the answer! I figured "install ZIP" would be pretty much the same as what the guide was instructing, but I also figured I'd err on the side of caution.